# Why isn't my project name in the Source Control drop down menu?

Tags: github, xcode9.2

I'm working with Xcode 9.2, and trying to put my project on GitHub. What can I do to make my project name appear in the Source Control drop down menu? I know it's supposed to be there for putting projects on GitHub and such. Thank you for your help :)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What can I do to make my project name appear in the Source Control drop down menu?

You project name will never appear in that menu. But simply add your GitHub login info in the Xcode Accounts preference pane:

[image]

Once you've done that, you can create Github repositories and clone from Github repositories directly within Xcode.

Comment: Thank you for your help! Where is that? In the info.plist or something?

Comment: Which part of "Xcode Accounts preference pane" is mysterious? Xcode. Preference. Accounts.

Comment: My mistake. Thank you!